# Why does my view's visibility change randomly?

Tags: java, android

I'm totally confused about my `TextView`'s visibility. I wanted it to slowly fade in, so i made this:

```
 Log.d("TESTCLICK", "ForgotTextView Visibility 1 : " + Integer.toString(forgotTextView.getVisibility()));

 forgotTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

 Log.d("TESTCLICK", "ForgotTextView Visibility 2 : " + Integer.toString(forgotTextView.getVisibility()));
 forgotTextView.setAlpha(0f);

 ViewPropertyAnimator editTextNameAnimator = nameEditText.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(1000);
 ViewPropertyAnimator editTextPasswordAnimator = confirmEditText.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(1500);

 editTextNameAnimator.setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                    nameEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Log.d("TESTCLICK", "ForgotTextView Visibility 4 : " + Integer.toString(forgotTextView.getVisibility()));
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

                }
            });

 editTextPasswordAnimator.setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                    confirmEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Log.d("TESTCLICK", "ForgotTextView Visibility 5 : " + Integer.toString(forgotTextView.getVisibility()));

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

                }
            });

 editTextNameAnimator.start();
 editTextPasswordAnimator.start();
 forgotTextView.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(1000).start();

 loginButton.animate().translationYBy(-100f).setDuration(1000).start();

 Log.d("TESTCLICK", "ForgotTextView Visibility 3 : " + Integer.toString(forgotTextView.getVisibility()));
```

So i basically change `TextView`'s visibility to `VISIBLE`, set's it's alpha to 0, and then animate it alongside other views, but the output form those logs looks like this [image]

So, everything until 4th log works fine, but then at 5th my `TextView` disappears, and it looks like it's Visibility changes back to `GONE`, like it was at the start (I especially changed this animation's duration to 1500 just to check the logs), why does that happen?

**EDIT**:
Solution to this is adding listener to `forgotTextView` animation and at the end of it changing it's visibility to `VISIBLE` **again**, so like double changing it, this way it won't change to `GONE` on it's own(or it will but you'll overwrite it). I still don't know why this is happening

Comment: Please check this, confirmEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE); you set visibility to gone before execute 5. It might work when u swap those lines.

Comment: Yeah, but that's a different view, i'm changing `confirmEditText`'s Visibility before 5, and i'm checking `forgotTextView`'s Visibility in the logs

Comment: Oh, someone deleted comment, so that's why i Log inside other views' listeners. -- Yeah, because `forgotTextView` disappears after finishing it's animation, so after 1 sec, then it's Visibility goes back to `GONE` without me calling it, i just needed a way to check it's Visibility after that 1 second, i could've done the same by adding A listener to `forgotTextView` animation and logging 5 in there, at the end of it's animation but i wanted to use less code here.